# Delete Rows for Dynamically Adjusted Table View?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to delete a row in a tableview. When the row is deleted, the tableview should adjust, so that there is not a blank row in the tableview. This is what it looks like before any rows are deleted:

[image]

This is what it looks like when a row is about to be deleted:

[image]

This is what it looks like after a row has been deleted:

[image]

There should not be that extra blank row after the fourth row is deleted. How do I get rid of this extra row?

Here is my code currently. As you can see, the size of the tableview is adjusted dynamically. The overall size of the tableview is different based on whether there are 4 items (as shown in the first image) or whether there are 6 items. In both cases, before any deletions occur, there are no extra rows in the table (so there are only 4 rows total in the first case, and only 6 rows total in the second case). In addition, the button is supposed to be 80 pixels below the ending of the tableview. When a row is deleted, the button moves correctly, as you can see that the button has moved up from images 2 to 3. However, it still looks like there is an extra row in the tableview.

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet var newButton: UIButton!

var items: [String] = ["Swift", "Is", "So", "Amazing"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! UITableViewCell

    // Make sure the table view cell separator spans the whole width
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // Adjust the height of the tableview
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.contentSize.height)

    // Add a border to the tableView
    tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    tableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
}

// This function is used for adjusting the height of the tableview
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.contentSize.height)
    tableView.reloadData()

    //Get the current height of the tableview
    var tableViewHeight = self.tableView.contentSize.height
    var tableViewEnding = 134 + tableViewHeight
    var buttonPlacement = tableViewEnding + 80

    // The New Button is 80 points below the ending of the tableView
    newButton.frame.origin.y = buttonPlacement

    print("Table View Height: \(tableViewHeight)")
}

// Allow cell deletion in tableview
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // delete item at indexPath
        self.items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        self.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        print(self.items)
        print("Number of rows: \(tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0))")
    }

    delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    return [delete]
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't call view lifecycle methods, such as `viewDidLayoutSubviews` directly. Also, setting frames directly is not ideal either. You should set constraints between your items and let autolayout move things around. Reloading the whole tableview after a delete will also have negative visual impact, particularly as your tableview gets larger.

Comment: I understand that constraints can ensure that the button is always 80 pixels below the end of the tableview. Is there a way for autolayout/constraints to solve the Row Deletion problem?

Comment: You will need to constrain the height of the tableview and then update the `constant` of that constraint as required. You should probably look at the tableview's `contentSize` property rather than its frame.

Comment: This worked! I added a constraint for the height of the tableview and then I updated that constraint. Thanks.

Comment: Also do you want to show the part of the TableViewCell, in your case "Amazing", to be visible when you are about to delete the row?

Answer (score 0):

Just add following in view did load method

```
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Now there will be no extra empty rows.

Next step is

Add Height constraint to tableview and take IBOutlet of it.

After any updates on tableview set constraints's constant value with tableview's `contentSize.height`

Note: If your cell has some heavy task to do then setting constant next to the reload data may not work properly in that case you may try viewDidLayoutSubviews methdo

Hope it is helpful